# How to pipe tail -f output into the shell script

Tags: bash, tail

I want to monitor server logs using telegram bot api with this script:

```
#!/bin/bash
CHATID="id"
KEY="key"
TIME="10"
URL="https://api.telegram.org/bot$KEY/sendMessage"
TEXT=$(tee)

curl -s --max-time $TIME -d "chat_id=$CHATID&disable_web_page_preview=1&text=$TEXT" $URL >/dev/null
```

Then pipe logs output to the script by using:

```
tail -f /var/log/my.log | ./telegram_log.sh
```

But it doesn't send the output.

Comment: what you want to achieve? sending a message on every new log line?

Comment: @MarcoLucidi yes, exactly this

Comment: you should process each incoming line then. at the moment, I think that your script remains stuck at `TEXT=$(tee)` waiting for `stdin` to end/close but it will never happen, because `tail -f` keeps it opened.

Comment: @MarcoLucidi should I use the loop then? Can you give an example?

Comment: yes a loop, I'm writing an example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your script remains stuck at the line

```
TEXT=$(tee)
```

because `tee` it's waiting for `stdin` to be closed, but it will never happen, because `tail -f` keeps it open to "follow" the file.

to send a message on each new log line you should process each incoming line and not waiting for the whole `stdin`. a simple `while read` should do it, for example:

```
$ more bot.sh
#!/bin/sh

while IFS= read -r line; do
        echo send new line as msg: "$line"
        # TODO here goes curl etc...
done
$ touch log
$ tail -f log | ./bot.sh
send new line as msg: hello
send new line as msg: world
send new line as msg: goodbye
```

and on another terminal i did:

```
$ echo hello >> log
$ echo world >> log
$ echo goodbye >> log
$
```